# How to Do this UI set revealing animation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am new to iOS development. Currently I'm developing a part from my previous Android app for learning purpose. I want to do following animation. I don't know a proper name for the animation so check below gif.

[image]

I have both text label with text field inside stack view. Can some one share the code for this animation or post a helpful link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such a case, I would suggest to use a [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) (vertical) to be the container for the components in the scene. When working with stack views, you could easily get such an animation for free! For applying the desired animation, the simplest way is to implement the popular UIView [animate(withDuration:animations:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animate) and hide the desired view in its `animations` block parameter:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
    self.viewToHide.isHidden = !self.viewToHide.isHidden
}
```

By following this approach, you would be able to create an animation -which is what are you looking for- like this:

[image]

<sub>Resource: [Easy Animation with UIStackView](https://medium.com/@nrewik/easy-animation-with-uistackview-8878b2856ae2).</sub>

**Official Reference:**

You could review [Mysteries of Auto Layout, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/) Apple Session (at *00:12:22*, it should contains the topic that you are asking about).

Comment: Good suggestion! That would be easier than my approach. (Voted.)

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you could handle that. Below is one way. (Note that Ahmad's suggestion of a stack view would be easier and cleaner.)

Place your views that you want to appear inside another view. I'll call this view a container view (although in this case I don't mean container view the way interface builder refers to a view that can hold a child view controller.) Set the `clipsToBounds` flag on the  container view to true.

Add a height constraint to the container view.

Select the constraint and control drag into your source file to make an outlet to the constraint. Note the current height value of the height constraint.

Now change the height value to zero. This should cause the views inside the container view to disappear.

When you want to animate those controls into place use a `UIView` animation that contains a call to `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`.  Set the height  constraint of the ContainerView to its nonzero value immediately before the call to `UIView.animate(duration:animations:)`.